# Adding user in Power BI workspace using Power BI Admin API returning unauthorized

Tags: rest, powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-api

I'm trying to use this API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-add-user-as-admin.

I'm authenticating with a Service Principal which has tenant.ReadWrite.All and Fabric Administrator role (previously Power BI Service Administrator).

With the token generated with the Service Principal, I'm able to run other Admin APIs like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-group-as-admin.

However, when running Add user as admin, I'm getting 401 unauthorized.

I'm runnning it with Python

```
group_id = '<workspace_id>'
aad_group_object_id = '<servicePrincipal_cliend_id>'
new_permission = 'Contributor'

url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/{group_id}/users'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    'principalType': 'App',
    'identifier': aad_group_object_id,
    'groupUserAccessRight': new_permission
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

I cannot see how there's an authorization issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran same code by passing service principal `clientID` for identity parameter and token generated with **client credentials** flow, I too got **same error** as below:

```py
token='<client_credentials_token>'
group_id = '<workspace_id>'
aad_group_object_id = '<servicePrincipal_client_id>'
new_permission = 'Contributor'

url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/{group_id}/users'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    'principalType': 'App',
    'identifier': aad_group_object_id,
    'groupUserAccessRight': new_permission
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Added successfully")
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code, response.reason)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass service principal `objectID` for identity parameter that can be found in **Enterprise applications** tab with same name:

[image]

In my case, I generated token using **username password** flow by granting `Tenant.ReadWrite.All` Delegated permission via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<appId>
client_secret:<secret> 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
username: admin@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran same code by passing above token and service principal `objectID` for identity parameter, I got **response** successfully like this:

```py
token = '<above_token>'
group_id = '<workspace_id>'
aad_group_object_id = '<servicePrincipal_object_id>'
new_permission = 'Contributor'

url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/{group_id}/users'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    'principalType': 'App',
    'identifier': aad_group_object_id,
    'groupUserAccessRight': new_permission
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Added successfully")
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code, response.reason)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Power Bi portal where service principal added with `Contributor` role like this:

[image]